# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'infer_objects'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Every time I try the method infer_objects(), even when following the official doc ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html?highlight=infer#pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects)), I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'infer_objects'
```

Example of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", 1, 2, 3]})
df = df.iloc[1:]
df = df.infer_objects()
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Note that says: *New in version 0.21.0.* - what does `pd.__version__` show you?

Comment: That might be that. My version is 0.20.3.

Comment: After update, it works now. Thanks for your help ;)
That's strange, I made a new install of Anaconda and Pandas last week-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can support Jon Clements answer and F. Varlets issue: updating pandas works

To avoid [convert_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) and [infer_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html):

**setting datatypes manually:**

```
In [21]: df=pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['b','2']], columns=['x','y'])

In [22]: df.dtypes
Out[22]: 
x    object
y    object
dtype: object

In [23]: for k in {'x':'object','y':'int'}:
    ...:     df[k]=pd.to_numeric(df[k], errors='ignore')
    ...:     

In [24]: df.dtypes
Out[24]: 
x    object
y     int64
dtype: object
```

**automatic datatype convertion:**

```
In [10]: df=pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['b','2']], columns=['x','y'])

In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]: 
x    object
y    object
dtype: object

In [12]: for k in list(df):
    ...:    ...:     df[k]=pd.to_numeric(df[k], errors='ignore')
    ...:    

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]: 
x    object
y     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: That's true, we can also do it like that :)
And finally, I prefer to set manually the type of my columns, as long as I don't need to define the data type on too many columns